# Sum involving powers of roots of unity

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, roots-of-unity

For $a\in\mathbb{N}^*$ we define:

$$ S(a)=\sum_{0\leq k \leq a-1} e^{i\pi \frac{k^2}{a}}  $$
or equivalently, if $\omega=e^{\frac{i\pi}{a}}$ is the primitive $2a$-th roots of units, we could write:
$$S(a)=1+\omega+\omega^{4}+\omega^{9}+\dots+\omega^{(a-1)^2}$$

How could you prove that $S(a)=1$ for odd values of $a$ and $S(a)=(i+1)\sqrt{(a/2)}$  if $a$ is even?

Comment: What's your try?

Comment: That's a *quadratic Gauss sum*.

Comment: Maybe $S(a) = -1$ for $a$ odd?

Comment: @Exodd: It's 1 but I've done an error with index, now I've corrected it, thanks

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown There isn't a direct proof not involving Gauss sums symbols?